Prove limit as $x\to 0$ of $(1/x)\sin(1/x)$

Prove limit as $x\to 0$ of $(1/x)\sin(1/x)$

See my working below, hopefully you find it legible.
Proving it using epsilon-delta, turned it into a proof by contradiction.
I assume the limit converges to some L in the Reals, then consider two cases where L≥0 and where L<0 and want to show that in either case the limit does not converge to L.
Therefore, the number L cannot exist and thus limit can't either.
Would appreciate some guidance on how to procede in that last step, not sure what 'epsilon' to pick to show that the expression in the absolute value is greater than epsilon.


Notice that your definition of "non-conergence" to $L$ is wrong. It should be $\exists \varepsilon >0:\forall \delta >0,\exists x_\delta :...$.Take the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and the sequence $y_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$ and see what happen...

Even if you complete the argument in those two cases you will have left out the possibilty of the limit being  $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

I suggest re-writing the original problem as $~\displaystyle \lim_{y \to +\infty} [ ~y \times \sin(y) ~],~$ and then consulting your intuition as to whether the limit exists.  For one thing, $~\sin(y)~$ will oscillate to sometimes having negative values and sometimes having positive values.  For another, $~y~$ will sometimes approach $~2k\pi \pm \pi/2 ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
